# Visual Studio installation progress drops after resuming download

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I had searched about this on the web, but couldn't find any information.

I am trying to download **Visual Studio 2019 community** edition via the **Visual Studio installer**. Since I use a limited daily internet pack, I want to pause the download for a day and resume it on the next day.

The problem is that, suppose, I pause the download at 500MB, when I resume it on the following day, the download again starts from 300MB. Moreover, sometimes the download progress drops by a few Megabytes.
What's the reason for this and how this problem can be overcomed?

Please tell me if you can't understand any part.

Comment: The download should return to 500MB after some time for both server and client to get going. Doesn't it?

Comment: But, it doesn't happen. The download actually resumes from 300MB.

Comment: It should slowly go up again to the limit supported by server+client plus local Internet traffic conditions.

Comment: But, as I have told that I have a limited daily data plan, so how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I think we are talking at cross meanings. If you are looking for a way to pause the download, most browsers have such a mechanism. Otherwise, you might be better off with a [Download Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-download-manager.htm). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: My browser supports this feature, but I am downloading Visual Studio using the Visual Studio installer, and that is causing this problem. By the way, is there any way to directly download Visual studio without using the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 does not have an offline installation that you can download
in segments. Its normal installation mode is to download and install everything
at once.

I suggest to try and create an offline installation.
I believe that in this mode, the installer will not reload modules that are
already present on the disk.

See the Microsoft article
[Create an offline installation of Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
which lists two way of doing so.

I recommend using the command:

```
vs_community --layout  "C:\Setup\VS2019Offline" --lang en-US
```

The article also describes the `--add` parameter, that can help in limiting
the size of the download. Downloading everything is a huge undertaking.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the thing I wanted. I would definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10py6lxVYQAhrU7ELxt4LTsurfTd2f2Mb/view

Download the required file and install on your laptop/desktop and then install visual studio installer. Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting beyond downloading a file by clicking a link?  Can you add some explanation?